# Edit buttons greyed out in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, gpx

I have imported GPX files from a Garmin 62s into QGIS, but the edit buttons remain greyed out despite reviewing folder permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit gpx files in QGIS. You must convert them: export/save them, e.g. as Geopackage file.